# Can I make MS-SQL Procedure in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a sql procedure with Java.

the reason why I have to make a procedure in Java is, the procedure will be locked once created.

Therefore, when I need to make some modification, I have to delete whole procedure and make a brand-new

procedure in Java.

Can this be possible? or should I find different way to do it?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Do you create one programmatically or actually write a stored procedure using the Java language?

Comment: I actually write(hardcode) stored procedure in Java. I just need to finda way to create the procedure hardcoded in Java and execute, in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the user that your code is using to connect to the DB has the correct permissions then you should just be able to execute the normal SQL to create the SP. Nothing special needed to do it from Java. Here are the permissions you need:

Permissions
Requires CREATE PROCEDURE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the procedure is being created.

An example of the SQL is:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2 
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department.
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName
    AND EndDate IS NULL;
GO
```

**Warning**
Let me also say that this is a generally bad idea to run an application this way. It's just so easy for something to go terribly wrong and your application does something crazy like delete a whole table. Just be careful with this especially if your application gets any input from a user. This is risky.

Comment: The database user which OP uses to connect to MSSQL must have the privileges, not the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. Because I had to encrypt the procedure(Not modify-able), I chose to delete the whole procedure and re-create. Luckly, I just solved my problem with using ASP file(asp creates and deletes procedure , not Java) Thanks anyways!